# Prevent comparevalidator from displaying error until button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a password textbox and confirm password textbox in which I use a `comparevalidator` to make sure that they are equal.  If they aren't, I want the user to receive an error message that says they don't match.  However, I don't want this to display until the user clicks a button.  What is currently happening is that when I tab from the first textbox to the second, I immediately receive that error.

How can I prevent this error from showing up until after I click a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple way to get around this would be to reverse the `ControlToCompare` and the `ControlToValidate`

```
<label>Password: <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></label><br/>
<label>Confirm Password:<asp:TextBox ID="confirmPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></label>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="password" ControlToValidate="confirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

By reversing these properties the validation should only occur when they tab off the confirm password text box. (*This assumes the user fills out the form top down and not bottom up, but who does that anyways*)

Comment: This is probably the best solution at the moment without applying javascript.